# Swift protocol declared in separate file

Tags: swift

My classes seem unable to find a swift protocol when it is declared in its own file.  Do they need to be declared with actual classes?

Moving the protocol into the class that is using it has resolved the problem, but I want to make the protocol more reusable than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, protocols and classes in Swift can be declared anywhere in the project.

I think you should check **Target Membership** setting of your file with a protocol. Target of the file must be the same as file with a class.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem while developing my own pod.  For reusability I decided to split the protocols out into their own file.

I had gotten lazy and stopped running "pod install" and everything was "just working".

After reading Egor's answer, I realized what "pod install" was actually doing and it fixed my problem.